# wso2 esb xslt transformation

Tags: wso2-esb

I want to do xslt transformation in wso2 esb using xslt mediator I wrote a xslt and tried it in a browser it worked fine but I am not able to call my xslt in xslt mediator in wso2 esb

Comment: Did it work? Please close this question or continue asking. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**A:** I'm always using a **local-entry** to reference my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="myXSLTlocalEntry" src="file:repository/resources/my.xslt"/>
```

**B:** The XSLT file is under following path **%WSO2_HOME%/repository/resources**

**C:** And then I call the XSLT mediator inside of a sequence with this command:

```
<xslt key="myXSLTlocalEntry"/>
```

More documentation about the XSLT Mediator can be found [on the WSO2 ESB Documentation Site](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/XSLT+Mediator): 
**D:** The XSLT must of course also map the Soap envelope and body (which is also passed to the XSLT). Then body element then contains your effective data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ds="ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope|soapenv:Body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ds:Entries">
        <!-- DO YOUR TRANFORMATION HERE -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: tnks for you reply but for eg I have an xml response like             \<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soapenv:Body>
         <Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <Entry>
               <empId>xxx</empId>
               <empName>yyy</empName>
               <allocatedDesk>null</allocatedDesk>
            </Entry>
         </Entries>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: and I want the output as     <Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <Entry>
               <empId>xxx</empId>
               <empName>yyy</empName>
               <allocatedDesk>null</allocatedDesk>
            </Entry>
         </Entries>     so what would be the xslt

Comment: the xslt which I wrote was <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   
 
 <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> didnt worked so what could be the mistake

Comment: Oh you just have to know that any message in WSO2 contains a SOAP envelope and body! I'll edit my answer and add an example of the XSLT...

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB uses AXIS2 as its  underlying SOAP engine..Here you are trying to eliminate soap tags, which will be present in the message lifecycle within axis2 scope. If you need to get only the message body, try to write a custom class mediator to get access for the synapse messagecontext and use following code snippet, which will return the child element of the soapbody.

```
 messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstChildWithName(**)
```